# How to get credentials of volume storage on softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have tried below methods, to get credentials of iscsi storage on softlayer( i have endurance block storage on softlayer) but unable to retrieve password.

```
SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi::getCredentials
eg. res = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi'].getCredentials(id=***)
SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi::getObjectsByCredential
SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi::getObject
SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi::getAllowedVirtualGuests
```

I want to retrieve username, password and iqn  for authorized host to specific volume. Are there any api's to retrieve this information or any other way to retrieve this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object mask to retrieve this kind of information:

> mask[allowedHardware[allowedHost[credential]],allowedVirtualGuests[allowedHost[credential]]]

This would be the usage on a REST request:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi/$iscsiId/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[allowedHardware[allowedHost[credential]],allowedVirtualGuests[allowedHost[credential]]]
```

And here a sample using Python client:

```
"""
Get credentials for a authorized hosts of a SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi 

Important manual pages
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

iscsiStorageId = 1234567

client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
networkStorageIscsiService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Iscsi']

objectMask = 'mask[allowedHardware[allowedHost[credential]],allowedVirtualGuests[allowedHost[credential]]]'

try:
    iscsiStorage = networkStorageIscsiService.getObject(mask=objectMask, id=iscsiStorageId)
    print(json.dumps(iscsiStorage, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to retrieve the Network Storage Iscsi. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" 
        % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

The next link might provide you further information:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks

Comment: Hi David...I am able to retrieve credentials with above steps thank you